# Can a npm package have a group value in the Nexus repo?

Tags: npm, nexus, nexus3

NPM packages

I published `angular2` component to `nexus npm repository`. When I viewed it form nexus console I can view it. Can npm packages may have group? Seems like there are 3 fields for npm published packages in the nexus console, name, `group`, version.

I'm using nexus `repository manager 3.2.1 pro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Nexus 3 docs](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/using.html) say:

> The npm Group is equivalent to the component group, also sometimes
>   referred to as scope by npm users.

The [npmjs Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) describes scope as optional:

> All npm packages have a name. Some package names also have a
>   scope.[...]When used in package names, scopes are preceded by an @
>   symbol and followed by a slash

So most of the time, the 'Group' column will be blank when browsing an NPM repository in Nexus 3. If you were to install a scoped package like @angular/router into your NPM Proxy repository inside Nexus 3, the Nexus Browse Components UI would show 'angular' in the Group column.